# Wrong indexing with unordered_map

Tags: c++, hash, reference, hashtable

I am having trouble to access the key of unordered_map. Following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int k = 2;
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    for(auto num : nums)
        mp[num]++;
    for(auto it : mp)
        cout << it.first;
    cout << endl;
    for(auto it : mp)
        cout << mp[it.first+k];
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be

> 54321
>
> 00111

because the key value of "7","6","5","4","3" are "0","0","1","1","1". But the output was

> 54321
>
> 0000

Note that there are only four "0" here. I am confused and do not know what the mechanism is. Could anybody help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are modifying the map while you are iterating over it, this is Undefined Behaviour

Comment: You have UB, When iterating over `mp` elements, you create new one by calling `[]`, so your loop is broken - `end` iterator of mp was changed.

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behavior because after this adding the new element `mp[it.first+k]` for `it.first` equal to 5 the iterators are invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question, what will happen if I do something like "vector<int> nums = {1,2,3,4,5}; for(auto num : nums) nums.push_back(num)"? I expected it to be infinite loop but it returns "1234511-2144292696132".

Comment: @YizeWang Again there is undefined behavior. For example the vector can reallocate memory when a new element is pushed on.